# Multiple remote servers for the same project

Tags: phpstorm

I am running a website that is stored on two remote servers. It's kind of a strange setup as there is no master/slave relationship, so when I make changes I have to deploy to both servers.

Is there any way to set up multiple (identical) remote servers for one project in PHPstorm so that I can save my changes simultaneously on both?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to set up multiple (identical) remote servers for one project in PhpStorm so that I can save my changes simultaneously on both?

Currently that is not possible: only one server at a time.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5134 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

**P.S.** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-909 seems to be partially related as well.

---

Maybe you can setup manual/auto-sync on one of the servers that will sync these servers from there (i.e. you upload to one and the sync will mirror changes to another server from there)?